# Load a editing form with data from firebase database using Swift

Tags: swift, reloaddata

I'm having a form that I want to populate the text fields with data the user has given previously for him/her to edit.

However when I'm trying to pull the data from firebase the array is empty. I feel it has something to do in the way I have written the code...

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Photos

class createProfileVC: UIViewController {

    var userArray = [User]()

    // Normal outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField! // required
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField! // required - type of hunt

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get userdata from Firebase
        DataService.instance.getUserdata(userId: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!) { (returnedUserArray) in
            self.userArray = returnedUserArray

        }

        self.firstName.text = userArray[0].firstName

    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see how `DataService.getUserdata` is structured to help.  As a quick note, `self.firstName.text = userArray[0].firstName` will execute before `getUserdata` is finished, so you should move that inside the brackets, just below `self.userArray.returnedUserArray`.  You will need to make sure that is performed on the main queue.

Comment: perhaps have look at the documentation for managing users: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_a_users_profile